# Java: java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException after building jar-file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have some code, using a text-file which is in a subfolder of my project in eclipse: ./data/subfolder/test.txt

The Folder structure is like the following:

```
Projectname
> src
>> mainpackage
>>> Main.java (this is executed when the jar is called)
> data
>> subfolder
>>> test.txt
```

Unfortunately the whole Code consits of many files so I can't post it here but the code works fine.

Now I exported the project as a jar-package and called this jar-file. When doing this I get the FileNotFoundException. What do I need to do, that the external file can be found also if the project is exported as a jar-file?

Do I need to do something that this is working? Does anybody know how to do that?

Any advice is helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post/screenshot the folder structure here?

Comment: Is the text file part of your jar or not?

Comment: @RahulYadav: I actually don't know I just exported the project as a jar-file. I never did this before. How can I know if it is part of the jar?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse's export to jar functionality, include the files that your program is dependent on inside the src folder itself.

Updated structure will look like this

```
Projectname
> src
>> test.txt
>> mainpackage
>>> Main.java (this is executed when the jar is called)
```

And in the program, you can easily get hold of it by using

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However the file mentionend above is not the only file I use. So is there any possibilitiy to solve this issue without changing the whole folder-structure?

Comment: Another way is to pass the root folder path as your java argument. But that way, everytime the application can only start after knowing the passed arguments.

Comment: I have other arguments to pass, so this shouldn't be a problem. But what do I do after passing the root folder?

Comment: The same way you are loading the files currently, load them. When loading the path changes as per the passed argument. Other than that, your program must be the same as it is now.

Comment: I am quite unsure how to do that. Just because I know the root-folder how can I open the files now?

Comment: How are you opening your files now? Using a Stream or a File or something of that sort?